# JQuery .find() not finding a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

First I know the title isn't the best nor what the site recommends/asks for, but I have no idea how else to put it.

I'm using JQuery to edit twitter widgets on my website. I had no problem doing so until this one element.

I have checked that I'm searching for the correct element `timeline-Widget` and what I'm trying to edit is the `border-radius`

[image]

snippet of my code:

```
$('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').css({"border": "4px solid rgb(255, 225, 241)", "outline" : "8px solid rgb(255, 189, 225)"});
$('.twitter-block').find('.timeline-Widget').css({"border-radius": "0px"});
```

first line edits `twitter-timeline` element and it works just fine, but `timeline-Widget` JQuery just does not find.

Sorry, this is my first time working on a website and a first time working with JS and JQuery

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: `find` will only look for elements in the current document, but the image suggests that the `.timeline-Widget` element is not in the current document, but in a child document. You would need a reference to that document first...

Comment: @barmar sorry, I took a better screenshot and edited my question.

Comment: A selector can't cross into an iframe.

Comment: An iframe with no src attribute, this is not the way jQuery find() works

Answer (score 1):

from [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/find/) own documentation:

> ```
>  the .find() method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements 
>  in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements
> ```

meaning the div twitter-block needs to be the parent of the timeline-Widget in order for it to be found, but from the looks of it the timeline-Widget is the first child of the body element